# Can i use a Lenovo power adapter with a groundless cord? Should I?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power

My Lenovo PSU has a C6 power cord inlet:

[image]

I tried plugging in a C7 power cord but it doesn't fit:

[image]

Should I assume that it was done on purpose because using a groundless power cord would be unsafe and/or damage the PSU or the computer?

Or can I go ahead and order one of these shady "cheater" adapters from Amazon?

[image]

Comment: Don't. The machine is designed to run grounded. Running non-grounded has a substantial chance of damaging your equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It's bad enough to use 2-to-3 prong adapters with dumb equipment like lights or motors, because of safety reasons.  Smart equipment like computers, stereo equipment, and other electronics require more stable sources of electricity.  Grounding helps stabilize the current throughout the whole house / building, so don't use 2-to-3 prong adapters at all.  If you building only has 2 prong outlets, please contact an electrician to determine the costs of upgrading.